# Expanding recently added songs

Tags: iphone, mediaplayer

In my iPhone is there a way to get more "recently added" songs?
I have about 100 songs and I have added recently 5, now in my "recently added" I've got only those 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Recently Added** is a smart playlist. In iTunes, select it, go to **File → Edit Smart Playlist**, and change the criteria. For example:

[image]

Re-syncing your iPhone will apply these changes.

Comment: The Edit Smart Playlist entry is disabled (note: i have selcted recently added from the left menu)

Comment: ah ok i found it! i wasn't selecting the right element in the left menu.